# How to extract version number from String in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

Using R, stringr or any other package how do I get a version number with this rule:

start when you see " v" and end when you see "_" or " "

Here is an example

```
example <- c("daata v2.0 jkdfajfkdal fdadjfk 398432", "data 432 dfafd v4.0_ dfakfld")
```

I want:

```
ex2 <- c("v2.0", "v4.0")
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `regexpr/regmatches` in `base R` to match the `v` followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) followed by a dot (`.`) and one or more digits

```
regmatches(example, regexpr("v[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?", example))
#[1] "v2.0" "v4.0"
```

Here we assume that all the elements have the pattern.  If they don't have a pattern, then `regexpr` returns an index of -1 and thus we don't get the value corresponding to it.  So, before we do the `regmatches`, should change those `-1` or use an index to return wherever it is -1 as NA.  But an easier option is `str_extract` which returns `NA` where there are no match

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(example, "v[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?")
```

Comment: This is great but what is there is no "."? Like what if there is both v2 and v2.0 in the same vector and you want to extract both?

Comment: @Mr.Biggums then,, just wrap it in a `()` and add `?`

Comment: @Mr.Biggums try `example <- c("daata v2.0 jkdfajfkdal fdadjfk 398432", "data 432 dfafd v4.0_ dfakfld", "daata v2 jkdfajfkdal fdadjfk 398432");regmatches(example, regexpr("v[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?", example))#
[1] "v2.0" "v4.0" "v2"`

Comment: Just did the only other problem I have is that there are some observations that don't match this and I just want some sort of na or something because I need to append the extracted string back into the original dataset

Comment: @Mr.Biggums I updated the post.  Hope it helps